# How to use perf_hooks to measure async operations?

Tags: node.js

Here is a code that describes two async operations performed by the `foo` method:

```
const foo = async () => {
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, Math.random() * 100);
  });

  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 100);
  });
};

Promise.all([
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo()
])
```

I want to measure how long does each async operation takes and then how long does each `foo` execution takes in total.

My first attempt was:

```
const { PerformanceObserver, performance } = require('perf_hooks');

const obs = new PerformanceObserver((items) => {
  console.log('performance-observer', items.getEntries());
});

obs.observe({
  entryTypes: ['measure']
});

const foo = async () => {
  performance.mark('A');

  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, Math.random() * 100);
  });

  performance.mark('B');

  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, 100);
  });

  performance.mark('C');

  performance.measure('A to B', 'A', 'B');
  performance.measure('A to C', 'A', 'C');
  performance.measure('B to C', 'B', 'C');

  performance.clearMarks();
};

Promise.all([
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo()
]);
```

However, this (as expected) throws an error:

```
(node:29277) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_INVALID_PERFORMANCE_MARK]: The "B" performance mark has not been set
    at Performance.measure (perf_hooks.js:396:13)
    at foo (/Users/gajus/Documents/dev/temp/test.js:30:15)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
```

This happens because there is no relation between an instance of `PerformanceObserver` and individual performance marks.

How to use [`perf_hooks`](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html) to measure async operations?

Comment: Note: I want to know times of individual executions, not just aggregate of all executions ever.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is no other way than to mark and measure after the `resolve`.

```
const foo = async () => {
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    performance.mark('A');

    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
      performance.mark('B');
      performance.measure('A to B', 'A', 'B');
    }, Math.random() * 100);
  });

  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    performance.mark('C');
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
      performance.mark('D');
      performance.measure('C to D', 'C', 'D');
    }, 100);
  });

  performance.clearMarks();
};

Promise.all([
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo(),
  foo(),
]);
```

Comment: Please note that the usage of `performance.clearMarks()` in the bottom of `foo` will globally remove all marks, so whichever `foo` resolves first will clear all! Especially the `C` (and even `A`) marks are cleared, which will in particular make all but the first `C to D` measurements invalid, as they will measure the time between program startup and their respective `D` mark. I think the correct way to do what I think we want here is to give each "fiber"/"thread"/"process" its own unique id and e.g. measure `C-${id}` until `D-${id}`. Note also that then you may move the `measure` calls out.